# Why is my react router calling apis twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have explored whole web for the solution but nothing worked for me as expected.
My Api's are being called twice, resulting in duplicating data in db. I want them to trigger just once.

Find the code below:

```
   <Route
        path="/apis/wallet_verification"
        render={(routerProps) => {
          //deals with some params
          console.log("I am triggering");

          axios.get(`http://website/apis/save_ride_payments?payment_type=WALLET`).then((saveRides) =>{
            
            console.log("I am inside get");

            axios.post(`http://website/apis/verify_token?token=${usertoken}`).then((response) => {

              if(response.data.status !== "error") {
                console.log("I am inside post");
                routerProps.history.push({
                  pathname: '/paymentsuccess',
                  state: {initRide}
                });
              }
            })
          })
          console.log("I am out");
          return (
            <div>
              Wallet Transaction
            </div>
          )   
        }}
      />
```

Output of console:

```
I am triggering
I am out
I am inside get
I am triggering
I am out
I am inside post
I am inside get
I am inside post
```

Network tab is showing this Api sequence:

```
save_ride_payments
verify_token
save_ride_payments
verify_token
```

my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Definitely, there might be some logical mistake. Would love if someone were to point that out.

Comment: You are making the data calls, GET and POST requests, right in the function body instead of in an `useEffect`, so they are executed anytime react renders the component for DOM diffing purposes.

Comment: @DrewReese Can you edit or write some portion of code to show how they should get called? It would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your Api call at every render. You need a useEffect hook to only do it once.

An arbitrary function, in this case the anonymous function you send to `component` is not a React Functional Component. To make it a component, you need 1. a named function and 2. this named function to have a Capital as first letter [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

To make your code work, you need to define the component you want to render, only then can you call useEffect.

Here is a quick example, with some missing props/variable as I am not sure how and where your are getting them:

**Your new component:**

```
const Wallet = ({ history }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://website/apis/save_ride_payments?payment_type=WALLET`)
      .then((saveRides) => {
        return axios.post(`http://website/apis/verify_token?token=${usertoken}`);
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status !== 'error') {
          history.push({
            pathname: '/paymentsuccess',
            state: {
              initRide
            },
          });
       }
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>Wallet Transaction</div>;
};
```

**Your route:**

```
<Route
    path="/apis/wallet_verification"
    component={(routerProps) => <Wallet history={routerProps.history}/>}
/>
```

If you are using react-router, you can use the useHistory hook to get the history object instead of sending it via props.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but now both Api's are being call thrice.
Can you suggest any other way around?

Comment: I would need more info on your implementation to help further, any way you can shared more code?

Comment: Backend is in Laravel... Backend is directly calling  'api/wallet_verification' route only once...
Here is gist of full App.js: 
https://gist.github.com/Maha-Waqar/3c1790e08e72014356a49a32bbebecf2

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are making the data calls, GET and POST requests, right in the function body instead of in an `useEffect`, so they are executed anytime react renders the component for DOM diffing purposes.

## Fix

Use an `useEffect` hook to run the requests once when the route matches and the anonymous component is rendered. Use an empty dependency array so the effect is called only once when mounted.

```
const WalletVerification = ({ history }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //deals with some params
    console.log("I am triggering");

    axios
      .get(`http://website/apis/save_ride_payments?payment_type=WALLET`)
      .then((saveRides) => {
        console.log("I am inside get");

        axios
          .post(`http://website/apis/verify_token?token=${usertoken}`)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.status !== "error") {
              console.log("I am inside post");
              routerProps.history.push({
                pathname: "/paymentsuccess",
                state: { initRide }
              });
            }
          });
      });
    console.log("I am out");
  }, []);

  return <div>Wallet Transaction</div>;
}
```

Since `App` is connected to a redux store updates to the store likely trigger a rerender. This has the effect of also rerendering route components if they use an inline function.

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
> router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
> given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
> results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
> children prop

Either use the `Route`'s `component` prop

```
<Route
  path="/apis/wallet_verification"
  component={WalletVerification}
/>
```

or the `render` prop and proxy the route props

```
<Route
  path="/apis/wallet_verification"
  render={renderProps => <WalletVerification {...renderProps} />}
/>
```

Additionally, you can use React's [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) Higher Order Component to further hint to React that the component shouldn't rerender.

> If your component renders the same result given the same props, you
> can wrap it in a call to `React.memo` for a performance boost in some
> cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
> rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

```
const WalletVerification = React.memo(({ history }) => { ... });
```

Comment: This is error I get here:
React Hook "React.useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: @DandyMandy Hmm, I suppose React isn't viewing the `render` function *as* a react component. Try instead using the `component` prop. I'll update answer. If that doesn't work then I would just factor it all into a named functional component and use `component={WalletVerification}` (as an example).

Comment: @DandyMandy Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue we could live debug on?

Comment: I transferred UseEffect Code into separate function and then called it in router..
no errors, but it again called api twice....

Means useEffect didn't do any good

Comment: Can you suggest something else? as its such a big code, can't transfer it to codesandbox

Comment: @DandyMandy Did you use an empty dependency array for the effect? Can you test with a dummy component that has a single `useEffect(() => console.log('mounted'), []);` and log how many "mounted" logs you see? Perhaps the parent component rendering the `Router` is rerendering and thus "remounting" the routes.

Comment: @DandyMandy Thanks, this and checking out your github gist for confirms that `App` is rerendering. I've updated my answer with ways to try and mitigate rerending children.

Comment: Drew, Really thanks for all your support.
I have used React.memo.. and still it does render twice.
I am screwed

Comment: I can't tell if you access more from redux in `App`, but if you could decouple (or reduce dependency) `App` from the redux store and push what is being accessed to components, like creating a PrivateRoute component that checks the `props.appState.isUserLoggenIn`. Seems the issue is more with `App` rerendering and the `Route`s rerender and not with the "wallet verification" component. Even if you abstracted out the effect logic to an async action the action would still need to be dispatched on mount, so you'd still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

edit your `next.config.js` to

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};
```

and restarting the app.